# Is there any way to count the most recent consecutive sells in SQL/Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

So I have this table and I want to calculate the most recently consecutive days of selling > 0.

[Table Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAAf9.png)

[Output Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLP3X.png)

Answer (score 0):

I did not get exactly what you want in the result, but I'll assume you want id-value, in the most recent date to the last.

This query may work on Big Query:

```
SELECT id, value AS result FROM "your_project.your_dataset.your_table" 
WHERE value > 0 ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 10;      --by limiting, you save money in Big Query, but if you need the whole historic, take this command out
```

Let me know if it worked!

Comment: Watch out ! LIMIT does NOT save you money (see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#do_not_use_limit_to_control_costs_in_non-clustered_tables)